# How can I write a Screenplay Task to test React components which pass keyboard state as props

Tags: java, serenity-bdd, ag-grid-react

I am trying to test the behavior of an ag-grid component which allows me to select a cell, either using the keyboard or a single click and the grid component captures the keypress and passes it to an editor component I have written as described [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#start-editing).

The following works and simulates the situation where the user clicks, hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, types <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but I want to also verify the correct behavior without the intermediate enter key, e.g. simulate a single click, click, types <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```java
actor.attemptsTo(
    Click.on(cell),
    new Performable() {
        @Override
        public <T extends Actor> void performAs(final T actor) {
            pricerPage.withAction().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
        }
    },
    Enter.theValue("5y").into(PricerPage.POPUP_TEXT_EDITOR).thenHit(Keys.ENTER)
)
```

I seem to be unable to have the <kbd>5</kbd> keypress passed to my component as expected, e.g. the following does not trigger the editor component in the same way as sending <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```java
actor.attemptsTo(
    Click.on(cell),
    new Performable() {
        @Override
        public <T extends Actor> void performAs(final T actor) {
            pricerPage.withAction().sendKeys("5").perform();
        }
    },
    Enter.theValue("y").into(PricerPage.POPUP_TEXT_EDITOR).thenHit(Keys.ENTER)
)
```

Is there a better way to send keys without a target or is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up debugging both my test and the webpage under test - I was able to observe that the keyboard event `key` attribute was set to 'Unidentified' rather than '5' similar to as described [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/440)

I guess the moral of the story is your mileage may vary if you're trying to automate using old locked down versions of browsers...